# Is there public information indicating that a company is multinational?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, accounting, international, balance-sheet

I’m in transfer pricing and I’m wondering if there are any filings that indicate that a company is multinational? If so, is there any information on the number of subsidiaries the multinational company has?